# How can i fix this code to link my spinner to display the name of the parish from the array populated using a class?

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I cant get the setAdapter to work correctly for my project. I need the String "Name" from my java class eg Aghyaran to display as an option within a spinner

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<parish> parishArrayList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    parishArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    parishArrayList.add(new parish(1, "Aghyaran", "Termonamongan, N.West Tyrone", "6.30pm", "10.00am"));
    parishArrayList.add(new parish(2, "Castlederg", "Castlederg, N.West Tyrone", "7pm", "11.00am"));


    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parishArrayList);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

 }
}
```

Comment: You should be to use custom adapter

Comment: how do i link that to my ArrayList

Comment: Try override toString() method of your parish class to return the field that you want to display. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display **only name like "Aghyaran"** you could use `List<String>` instead of `ArrayList.

```
List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
categories.add("Aghyaran1");
categories.add("Aghyaran2");
categories.add("Aghyaran3");
categories.add("Aghyaran4");
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

More: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm

If you need to work with **all `parish` object** you must create a custom adapter.
More: https://www.codingdemos.com/android-custom-spinner-images-text/

Comment: Thanks but would this then work if i want it to link with an object within the parish class? 
I want to be able to display the names eg "Aghyaran" and "Castlederg" in a spinner list and then when the user selects these it then displays another string stored as a variable within the object

Comment: @OisínJohnMcHugh it's would work if you will use custom adapter